# How to style a component "from the outside" with scoped css

Tags: css, reactjs, vue.js, scoped

I'm using scoped CSS with https://github.com/gaoxiaoliangz/react-scoped-css and am trying to follow the following rules (besides others):

- Scoped component CSS should only include styles that manipulate the "inside" of the component. E.g. manipulating `padding`, `background-color` etc. is fine whilst I try to stay away from manipulating stuff like `margin`, `width`, `flex` etc. from within the component CSS
- Manipulating the "outside" of a component (`margin`, `width`, `flex` etc.) should only be done by "consuming" or parent components

This is rule is somewhat derived from some of the ideas behind [BEM](http://getbem.com/) (and probably other CSS methodologies as well) and allows for a rather modular system where components can be used without "touching their outside" but letting the parent decide how their internal layouts etc. works.

Whilst this is all fine in theory, I don't really know how to best manipulate the "outside styles" of a component from the consuming code which is best shown with an example:

**search-field.scoped.css** (the component)

```
.input-field {
  background: lightcoral;
}
```

**search-field.tsx** (the component)

```
import './search-field.scoped.css';

type SearchFieldProps = {
  className: string;
};

export const SearchField = (props: SearchFieldProps) => {
  return <input className={`input-field ${props.className}`} placeholder="Search text" />;
};
```

**sidebar.scoped.css** (the consumer)

```css
.sidebar-search-field {
  margin: 16px;
}
```

**sidebar.tsx** (the consumer)

```
import './sidebar.scoped.css';
// ...

export const Sidebar = () => {
  return (
    <SearchField className="sidebar-search-field" />
    (/* ... */)
  );
};
```

In the above example, the CSS from the class `sidebar-search-field` in `sidebar.scoped.css` is not applied because the class passed to `SearchField` is scoped to the `Sidebar` and the final selector `.sidebar-search-field[data-sidebarhash]` simply doesn't match as the `input` element of the `SearchField` (obviously) doesn't have the data attribute `data-sidebarhash` but `data-searchfieldhash`.

ATM, I tend to create wrapper elements in situations like this which works but is rather cumbersome & clutters the markdown unnecessarily:

```
// ...
export const Sidebar = () => {
  return (
    <div className="sidebar-search-field">
      <SearchField />
    </div>
    (/* ... */)
  );
};
```

## Question

Is there any way to "style scoped CSS component from the outside"?

*Ps.:* I'm not sure if all the above also applies to scoped styles in Vue. If not, please let me know how it works there so that I can create a feature request in https://github.com/gaoxiaoliangz/react-scoped-css.

Comment: You may want to use modular CSS. It looks like react-scoped-css tries to reinvent the wheel and probably not the best one, considering it's small third party lib with limited maintenance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "modular CSS"? Do you mean [CSS modules](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/) which come out of the box with `create-react-app`? If so, I'm aware of that option but I don't really like the debugging experience as CSS classes are not the same in code and in dev tools (for obvious reasons) which is why I'm started to use scoped CSS in the first place. However, I might consider other options if I don't find no other way for this...